# Style for different dimensions

Tags: java, android

I have a question considering extending styles in android:

```
<style name="SomeStyleName" parent="@android:style/DeviceDefault.SegmentedButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:weightSum">2</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">8dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
</style>
```

What if I would like to "extend" this default style for sw800dp and only to change one parameter (android:paddingBottom)?
Should I write only the parameter? Or all the data? (in values-sw600dp/styles.xml file of course)

Something like?:

```
<style name="SomeStyleName" >
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">33dip</item>
</style>
```

Comment: re write all other items also....

Answer (score 1):

What if I would like to "extend" this default style for sw800dp and only to change one parameter (android:paddingBottom)? Should I write only the parameter? Or all the data? (in values-sw600dp/styles.xml file of course)

---

you have to copy all the properties to values-sw600dp/styles.xml too.

But you can use the one `values/styles.xml` for all the screen resolution with the help of `values/dimens.xml`, `values-sw600dp/dimens.xml`...  and add a dimension for padding_bottom.
in all the dimens.xml in different values folder,use this dimen rather than hardcoding eg. `android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_bottom"` in `values/styles.xml`

so your values/styles.xml look like this:-

```
<style name="SomeStyleName" parent="@android:style/DeviceDefault.SegmentedButton">
<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:weightSum">2</item>
<item name="android:dividerPadding">8dip</item>
<item name="android:paddingTop">0dip</item>
<item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/padding_bottom</item>
<item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
<item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
```

**values/dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="padding_bottom">0dp</dimen>
```

**values-sw600dp/dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="padding_bottom">33dip</dimen>
```

So no need to create `values-sw600dp/styles.xml`

folder structure look like this:-

- values/

  - styles.xml
  - dimens.xml
- values-sw600dp/

  - dimens.xml
- values-sw720dp/

  - dimens.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can use dimens.xml in values folder
And redefine needed dimensions in values-sw600dp and other

for example
your main dimens.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

dimens.xml for sw800dp

```
 <resources>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">32dp</dimen>
</resources>
```